# Unable to create application in AOSP

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-source

Actually, im trying to add a source code of app in the AOSP but when i do the "make" and launch the emulator, the app is there but it's crashing, in the logcat it says "unable to create application" securityException. Each and every mk file is correct but the app is crashing.

Comment: Please add more details like maybe some basic code, and the error trace log

Comment: Unable to create application com.sasken.libservice.SaskenLibraryApplication: java.lang.SecurityException:
07-14 20:06:10.718  8314  8314 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6767)
07-14 20:06:10.718  8314  8314 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:256)
07-14 20:06:10.718  8314  8314 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2091)
07-14 20:06:10.718  8314  8314 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)

Comment: These are the crash logs im getting

Comment: Can you snip your code?

Comment: Thank you all for your response, it's solved, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, there were some updates for the branch, so I updated those. After that, I started the "make clobber" not "make clean" and then I did the "make". During the make, there were two options for config.txt file to choose(one is to update this file and other is to modify), here i did the update & again did the make. Now it's working fine.